# Android getDisplayMetrics() not returning accurate display size

Tags: java, android, pixel, screen-size, pixel-density

I'm trying to get the pixel width/height of the device for placing elements and mapping touch events on the screen but not getting the desired effect (notice lower right square should be completely flush with the bottom right):

[image: White square should be flush in the lower right corner]

```
// screen size
    DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
    float ScrDensity = metrics.density;
    int metricHeight = metrics.heightPixels;//
    int metricWidth = metrics.widthPixels;//

    Log.i("AllMetrics", metrics.toString());

    // temp
    int rightButton_diameter = 100;
    int rightButton_xpos = metricWidth - rightButton_diameter;
    int rightButton_ypos = metricHeight - rightButton_diameter;
```

Where AllMetrics returns:

```
DisplayMetrics{density=2.0, width=720, height=1184, scaledDensity=2.0, xdpi=320.0, ydpi=320.0}
```

I notice that the returned height is also different from the 720x1280 listed in the Virtual Device Manager (API 19, Android 4.4) and the x/y positions of the touch events seems accurate to the drawn elements (ie the clickable area of the button is the same as where it is being drawn)

**Is this a configuration error or am I using the incorrect method of fetching screen position?**

Comment: height=1184 since it doesnt include statusbar height which is 96, those two numbers added together give 1280 which is physical screen height

Comment: BTW what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Just accurately place things on the screen for starters.

I notice if I draw starting from 0,0 it's flush with the top left. Shouldn't the status bar be offsetting that by 69? Otherwise it's just missing height off the bottom rather than the top.

Comment: i have no idea what you mean,  sorry

Comment: Did you every find a sensible solution?  I am facing the same dilemma.

Answer (score 4):

Check this code it works for me

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int width = dm.widthPixels;
int height = dm.heightPixels;
```

Outside of activity you can try this

```
 ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm)
```

Comment: My understanding is that getWindowManager() can't be used outside of the main Activity? (and indeed returns 'cannot resolve method' when I try to use it)

Apologies if I'm mistaken. This is my first furore into Android dev.

Comment: if you want to use outside activity the pass activity context...good luck.

Comment: Is it then just accessed as a method of the main activity context? Using:
this.mainActivityContext.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm); returns the same issue, getWindowManager() not resolved.

Comment: i update ans please check now its working, i check on lolipop

Comment: This returns **1794 px** for Nexus 5X, whereas it should be **1920 px**: https://material.io/devices/

Answer (score 0):

To access the DisplayMetrics members, initialize an object like this:

DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
 getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);